Minimum conditions in order to make this integral equal zero
What is the minimum condition to impose in $F_{\bf B}$ and $G_{\bf B}$ in order to make this integral equal to zero?
\begin{equation}
   \int \left(\nabla\times F_{\bf B}\right)C({\bf x}) \left(\nabla\times G_{\bf B}\right) d{\bf x} 
 \end{equation}
where $C({\bf x})$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix given by
\begin{equation}
   C({\bf x}) =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & x_3 & -x_2 \\
   -x_3 & 0 &x_1 \\
   x_2 & -x_1 & 0
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}
and $F_{\bf B}$ and $G_{\bf B}$ are smooth vector fields
